# Admob native ads in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, xml, view, android-jetpack-compose, admob

I am trying to implement a basic Native ad from adMob to fit the design of my app in **Jetpack Compose**, but I don't understand how the onClick is supposed to be handled.

I know that it is possible using Viewbinding, but there has to be a Jetpack Compose way as well, as this is supposed to be the future of android development.

My full composable:

```
object Advertising {
        var currentImageAd: NativeAd? by mutableStateOf(null)
    }
    
    @Composable
    fun ImageAd(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, adId: String, nativeAd: NativeAd?, setNativeAd: (NativeAd?) -> Unit) {
        val context = LocalContext.current
        var iconPainter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
            model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                .data(nativeAd?.icon)
                .size(coil.size.Size.ORIGINAL)
                .build()
        )
    
        DisposableEffect(Unit) {
            val adLoader = AdLoader.Builder(context, adId)
                .forNativeAd { ad ->
                    if (nativeAd == null) {
                        setNativeAd(ad)
                    }
                }
                .withAdListener(object : AdListener() {
                    override fun onAdFailedToLoad(loadAdError: LoadAdError) {
                    }
                })
                .withNativeAdOptions(NativeAdOptions.Builder().build())
                .build()
    
            adLoader.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
    
            onDispose {
    
            }
        }
    
        nativeAd?.let { adData ->
            Box.SimpleBox(modifier,
                icon = R.drawable.advertisement,
                iconColor = colors.ad,
                headline = adData.headline,
                body = adData.body
            ) {
                Row(modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Max), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(Padding.ContentSeparation.standard)) {
                    Image(painter = iconPainter,
                                contentDescription = null,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxHeight()
                                    .aspectRatio(1f)
                            )
                    Button_Basic(shape = Shapes.tight, 
                         color = colors.ad, 
                         text = adData.callToAction ?:"Mehr", 
                         icon = R.drawable.web_exit, 
                         onClick = { 
                               //What to call here? 
                         })
                }
            }
        }
}
```

`Box.SimpleBox` is just a Box Container with rounded corners and `Button_Basic` a clickable Box with text. The Advertisements headline, body and callToAction text all all loaded and displayed correctly, but I do not understand how you are supposed to get the onClick to work.

It seems like the AdMob Sdk handles onClick for traditional views in Xml by using the ads assets automatically, but it don't know how to get it to work in Compose. Also it seems weird to not be able to create a custom Button for a Native ad which is supposed to be customisable.

Is this just not possible in Compose yet and I need to write the ad code in XML or how do I have to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct support for the NativeAd in Jetpack Compose so we have to manually do all the stuff.

First of all we will use Typical XML based system in Jetapck Compose

So just enable it in build.gradle(app-module)

add dependency

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-viewbinding:1.6.0-rc01"
```

enable features

```
buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
```

create layout in res/layout folder

**layout_native_ad_medium.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ad_background_color">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView
        android:id="@+id/nativeAdView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="60dp">

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.AdChoicesView
                android:id="@+id/adChoice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ad_rounded_corners_shape"
                android:paddingHorizontal="4dp"
                android:paddingVertical="1dp"
                android:text="Ad"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="5dp" />

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.MediaView
                android:id="@+id/mv_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_app_icon"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mv_content"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_headline"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_app_icon"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv_app_icon"
                tools:text="Test Ad : Google Ads" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_body"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:paddingVertical="2dp"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_app_icon"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_headline"
                tools:text="Stay up to date with your Ads Check how your ads are performing Checkit now" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_cta"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_body"
                tools:text="INSTALL" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView>

    <com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/shimmerFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_cta1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Loading Ad..."
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />


    </com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And Make a composable which will use the ViewBinding and access the layout file.

```
@Composable
fun NativeMediumAd() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val adUnit: String = "native_ad_id"
    var isAdRequested = false

    AndroidViewBinding(
        factory = LayoutNativeAdMediumBinding::inflate,
        modifier = Modifier
            .navigationBarsPadding()
            .wrapContentHeight(unbounded = true)
    ) {
        if (isAdRequested)
            return@AndroidViewBinding
        val adView = nativeAdView.also { adView ->
            adView.adChoicesView = adChoice
            adView.bodyView = tvBody
            adView.callToActionView = btnCta
            adView.headlineView = tvHeadline
            adView.iconView = ivAppIcon
            adView.mediaView = mvContent
        }
        kotlin.runCatching {
            AdLoader.Builder(adView.context, adUnit)
                .forNativeAd { nativeAd ->
                    nativeAd.body?.let { body ->
                        tvBody.text = body
                    }

                    nativeAd.callToAction?.let { cta ->
                        btnCta.text = cta
                    }

                    nativeAd.headline?.let { headline ->
                        tvHeadline.text = headline
                    }

                    nativeAd.icon?.let { icon ->
                        ivAppIcon.setImageDrawable(icon.drawable)
                    }

                    adView.setNativeAd(nativeAd)
                }
                .withAdListener(object : AdListener() {
                    override fun onAdLoaded() {
                        super.onAdLoaded()

                        shimmerFrameLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                        adView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }

                    override fun onAdFailedToLoad(p0: LoadAdError) {
                        super.onAdFailedToLoad(p0)

                    }
                })
                .withNativeAdOptions(
                    NativeAdOptions.Builder().setAdChoicesPlacement(ADCHOICES_TOP_LEFT).build()
                )
                .build()
        }.onSuccess {
            it.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
            isAdRequested = true
        }
    }
}
```

Note : just use `NativeMediumAd()` composable in your code and it's done.

Happy Compose !!